# Kafka Topic is not getting created when connecters are running sucessfully

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

i am pretty new to Confluent Kafka Data platform. I wanted to load data from database (i.e Snowflake here ) to Kafka .
I have created a JDBC source connecter for Snowflake . It got successfully registered and running with out any error. As per my understanding whenever connecter register successfully,  Kafka should be create a  topic as prefix+Tablename . But if you see the below diagram ,it is not creating any topic for It

[image]

What could be the issue ?? Any idea idea how to debug end to end pipeline ??

Below are connecters config parameter

[image]

Comment: Source connectors don't need to automatically create topics. Especially if that has been disabled at the cluster level. You should check the logs of the connect server to verify its not silently throwing `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION` warnings

Comment: how to check  logs of the connect server ?? Could you please help

Comment: Well, how did you start Kafka Connect?

Comment: confluent local start

Comment: `confluent logs connect`